# Adding Placeholder in select list OR Hiding Select list option on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I want to add the placeholder in select list(ie. Something appear by default in select list until user select some option). To do this with the actual select list, I figure out the way, I add the placeholder at 0th index and set display:none for that option.

This works fine on Chrome and Firefox.

Please check this 
[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/spidiweb/u61k34y1/) for demo.

But, this does not work on IE.

Is there any way to hide it on IE? Or is there any other way to add the placeholder to select list?

For more clarity, please check this Screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/5Bw95AYNCL

Comment: have you tried this?
`<option selected>1</option>`

Comment: Works fine for me in IE 11 and Edge.

Comment: @roll Your way will make the option with text 1 selected by default. This will not make Select as the placeholder.

Comment: @ChrisG 
It is not working for me. Could you please verify once again? I want that the Select must appear when list is Closed and the option must not appear when list is expended. This is working fine on Chrome and Firefox. Please compare behavior on IE with Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: I do think it works correctly, but the difference is that in chrome/ff the original selectbox keeps it's border on the bottom. And that disappears in ie.